# 3D box dimensions

Tags: plotting, image3d

How can I set the dimensions of the box of a 3D function, without influencing the function?

For example I want to see this function `Plot3D[x + y, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]` in a box 10 x 10 x 10, but I want the function image to remain the same, without extending as this command does: `Plot3D[x + y, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`

I would want to see the function as a piece of cheese floating in the middle of a box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Plot3D[x + y, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRangePadding -> {2, 3}]
```

[image]

Also

```
Plot3D[ConditionalExpression[x + y, -3 <= x < 3 && -2 <= y <= 2], 
       {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
Plot3D[Piecewise[{{x + y, -3 <= x < 3 && -2 <= y <= 2}}, Indeterminate],
       {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
(* same picture *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `PlotRange` option.  `PlotRange -> {10,10,10}`.